# Text Alignment Issue with Josefin Sans compared to Open Sans

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm facing an issue with vertical text alignment when switching between two fonts—Josefin Sans and Open Sans—in a div element. The text appears perfectly centered when I use Open Sans, but it shifts towards the top when I use Josefin Sans.

Here's the code snippet for the div:

```
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "green",
    fontSize: 36,
  }}
>
  SOME TEXT
</div>
```

Screenshot with [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans):

[image]

Screenshot with [Josefin Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans):

[image]

I've tried using CSS flexbox and adjusting the line-height, but neither method seems to correct the alignment issue.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any idea why this might be happening and how to fix it?

### **UPDATE**

My use case is simple one. I just wanted to use Josefin Sans font my application. I tried it with [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com/). When I use Josefin Sans font inside a Button component it was shifted to top. But with Open Sans it aligned center vertically.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/delicate-sun-m4zplk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: What happens if you have the two phrases next to each other (i.e. are they using the same baseline).

Comment: Every font family has their own alignment and spacing inside of their line-height. Every font-family is unique.  If you could provide some CSS or an example, I'm sure I could help you figure our a specific solution.

If you're trying to align to each other, flexbox `align-items: baseline` would work, but it's hard to say what you need without knowing the use case.

Comment: I have explained my use case and added a demo link. @davidleininger

Comment: @Arunwij This is a perfect example of a font-family having it's only spacing and alignment. Josefin is shifted up about 5px compared to Open Sans. If you want Josefin to align to the center of a button, give it a 5px padding. That should center it for you. That said, it could cause some other issues throughout your app. Just something to be aware of when picking a font.

Comment: Hey @davidleininger, thanks! Any chance there's a fix for this that I could use across the board (globally)? Like for divs, buttons, etc?

Comment: What this boils down to is : what do you mean by vertically centering text? As far as I know, the ‘optical center’ of characters in a font is not defined and fonts all have their own ideas on descenders and ascenders. It’s a fluke that open sans looks vertically centered.

Comment: The only way I have vertically centered a phrase satisfactorily is to draw it on a canvas and find the actual top and bottom, the extremities, of the characters.

Comment: @Arunwij you shouldn’t really need to fix this across the board, just where you want it vertically centered. It will work with itself all the time. Also, you may need to adjust the padding top as the font size grows.